# Straight line segment

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to show that the straight line segment joining two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ in a plane is the shortest path between $p_1$ and $p_2$.

I have tried the following:

The straight line segment joining two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ is $l(t)=p_1+t(p_2-p_1)$.
The length of the straight line segment is $\int_0^t \sqrt{l'(t)^2}=|p_2-p_1|$.
Suppose that the shortest path is given by $f(t)$ that does not represent a straight line segment.
We have $\int_0^t \sqrt{g'(t)^2} dt < \int_0^t  \sqrt{l'(t)^2}dt \Rightarrow g'(t)<l'(t) \Rightarrow g(t)<l(t)+c$ since $l,g$ are positive functions.
So $g$ could be either a polynomial of first order or a constant.
If it is a polynomial of first order, it will be a straight line segment, contradiction.
So $g$ has to be a constant.
But a constant can't join two different points.
Thus, the straight line segment joining two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ in a plane is the shortest path between $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Is it right? Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: $g'(t)<l'(t) \not\Rightarrow g(t)<l(t)+c$ in general. But more importantly: $l'(t)$ is a vector, so what is $l'(t)^2$?

Comment: @Jonas If we replace $l'(t)^2$ and $g'(t)^2$ by their norm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a function $y(x)$ such that, given two points $A=(a,y(a))$ and $B=(b,y(b))$, the length of the path from the two points is minimized.

This [length is given by the integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating):
$$
l=\int _a^b\sqrt{1+y'^2} dx 
$$
and your problem is classical problem in [Calculus of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations):

> Find the function $y(x)$ such that the functional
>   $$
> \int _a^bL(x,y,y')dx=\int _a^b\sqrt{1+y'^2} dx 
> $$
>   is minimized.

For the Lagrangian $L=\sqrt{1+y'^2}$ we have:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=0 \qquad \frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}=\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}
$$
so the [Euler-Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler.E2.80.93Lagrange_equation) equation is:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=0
$$
that gives:
$$
\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=C \iff y'^2=C^2(1+y'^2) \iff y'=\frac{C}{\sqrt{1-C}}=m
$$
so : $y=mx+q$ that is a straight line and the boundary conditions for the points $A$ and $B$ give the line between these points.

Comment: I see... Thank you!!! Is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: Your element line $\sqrt{y'^2} dx$ is wrong and the key point in this kind of problems is that the minimizing process depend on a variation of the function that cannot be siply reduced to  a variation of the independent variable.